# multiple ip with different gateways for my Eth port at laptop

Tags: networking, ip

I want to use three different ip on my laptop with different gateways.

i have tried the following steps.

Added ip in advance setting with different gateway.

but at a time only one ip is working.

i want to work on all ip at the same  time.

Is it possible ??

Or suggest me the way to work on this situation.

Comment: Which operating system are you using?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to assign each ip on different vlan interface. You can also assign ip on virtual interfaces (aliases) but in that case you cannpt assign different gateways. You didn't specify the os you are using so it's impossible to tell you how to do that.

Answer (score -1):

This is not possible unless you have multiple physical network interfaces. A network interface can only have on IP address at a time.

If you want to do this, I would buy some external USB network interfaces and assign each one, one of  your IP addresses.

Comment: No, in fact it is possible, but without further details, impossible to tell how

Comment: At least on Linux you can add any number of IP addresses to the same network interface: `ip addr add 10.70.0.3/24 dev eth0; ip addr add 10.90.77.33/24 dev eth0` ...

Comment: apparently you learn something new every day. Thanks for the info